# finite morphism (algebraic) vs finite morphism (analytic)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two algebraic varieties (reduced schemes of finite type) over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $f : X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Let $X^{an}$, $Y^{an}$ and $f^{an}$ the corresponding analytified objects.

Is it true that $f$ is a finite morphism of schemes if and only if $f^{an}$ is a finite morphism of complex analytic varieties ? (i.e. $f^{an}$ sends closed subset to closed subset and each fiber $f^{-1}(y)$, $y \in f^{an}(X^{an})$ is a finite set) ?

Comment: I think that this is true if $f^{\mathrm{an}}$ has "constant" fibers, e.g. $f^{\mathrm{an}} : X^{an} \to X^{an} / G \simeq Y^{an}$ is a quotient map (where $G$ is a finite set). In that case, I guess that $f^{-1}( \mathrm{Spec}(A) ) \simeq \mathrm{Spec}(A) \times G \simeq \bigsqcup_{x \in G} \mathrm{Spec}(A) \simeq \mathrm{Spec}(A^{|G|})$, meaning that $f$ is a finite morphism.